# How event hook works wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, hook

Hi i'am interesting about understand how an hook work.
In particular:
The callback are executed by a different thread or in the gui thread?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The callback executed in the calling thread nor in different nor in UI.

Comment: And who is the caller thread of the callback if my callback are associated to Keydown event?

Comment: in this case - the UI thread. AFAIK all the `Window` events normally are invoked on the UI thread.

Comment: Ok, I had try to put the instruction : while(true) inside a callback
But the graphic wasn't locked. 
So it proof that they are not executed in the Ui thread no?